# Error:Execution failed for task ':app:transformClassesWithDesugarForDebug'

Tags: java, android, execution

I am trying to run an app that my team are developing, but android studio keeps saying this :

> Error:Execution failed for task ':app:transformClassesWithDesugarForDebug'.
>   com.android.build.api.transform.TransformException:
>   java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.RuntimeException: com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: Error while executing java process with main class com.google.devtools.build.android.desugar.Desugar with arguments {@C:\Users\Anis\Documents\android-pos-v2\app\build\intermediates\tmp\desugar_args7946564509325145732}

I have tried to find solutions on the forum and on google, but nothing worked for me. I have even deleted the whole project and downloaded it again, but the same issue appears again and again. 
And what is surpring is on the laptops of my team they can run the app,, but not on mine.

***Edit***: I forgot to post this info (quite in a hurry yesterday)
So in my gradle, Android studio says that there is an error :  "All support libraries must be the use the exact same version specification".

But on the laptop of my coworkers they don't have the issue whereas we have the exact same gradle.

Here is the part of the gradle where it says something is wrong :

```
compile files('libs/powermock-mockito-1.7.1-full.jar')
compile 'com.android.support:design:25.3.1'
compile 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:25.3.1'
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.3.1'
```

This support library :

```
compile 'com.android.support:design:25.3.1
```

is underlined in red, it is written this :

> "All support libraries must be the use the exact same version specification"

The SDK version and tools version are :

```
    compileSdkVersion 25
    buildToolsVersion '26.0.2'
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.hottab.pos.v2"
        minSdkVersion 15
        targetSdkVersion 21
        versionCode 1031
        versionName "1.0.31"
        multiDexEnabled true
        testInstrumentationRunner 
        "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
         vectorDrawables.useSupportLibrary = true
    }
```

I am not sure if this the reason why I have the problem that I stressed before in my post, but maybe if I can fix this it can solve the problem. But I am a newbie and I don't really know how to fix this.

Can someone help me?
Thank you very much

Comment: you try clear and rebuid project again

Comment: there is hardly any solution for this, clean and rebuild not working, let me know if you find any solution.

Comment: Hi ! I have tried but it didn't wo. I have also tried to delete all the project and dowoaded it again from our team sourcetree, but still the same issue. So far nothing has worked. I have tried also to sync project with gradle files but didn't work.
I forgot to add in my post something (I was in a hurry). In the gradle I have an error. It says : "All support libraries must be the use the exact same version specification". I edit my post to show you the gradle and where it is wrong

Comment: Hi again ! Sorry for the double post, but I think this post needed to be separated from the previous one. So I have solved the issue : the problem was that the application I tried to run asks a lot of memory and my computer didn't have enough memory or an strong enough processour. So basically the solution is to add more RAM or replace the processor to a more powerful one (adding more RAM is enough)